# Can't see hostname on LAN device

Tags: networking, hostname, dhcp

I am trying to get my Android 2.3.5 phone to list all of the possible Raspberry Pis (running Raspbian) on my LAN network.
There are other devices on the network, so the way I thought to go about doing this, in pseudo code, was:

```
foreach ip 0..254
    hn = gethostname("192.168.0." + ip);
    if(hn == "rpi*") {
        do_something();
    }
```

I have successfully set the hostname of the RPi with:

```
sudo hostname rpi0
```

My router shows that the RPi is connected to `192.168.0.4`.
I am able to `ping` the ip address `192.168.0.4` from my Win7 PC, however I cannot `ping` the hostname, or `nslookup` the ip or hostname.

When I try the code below in java on my phone, it claims it is reachable, but the get hostname line returns the ip address rather than the hostname, which I think it is supposed to do if it cannot find a hostname:

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddress);
Log.d(TAG, inetAddress.isReachable(5000));
Log.d(TAG, inetAddress.getHostName());
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Is this even a sane way to go about finding all of one type of device on a LAN? If so, I am fairly sure that I have the android side of things correct, but I don't know that much about LANs.

PS sorry if this question is long and convoluted, I wanted to include everything I had tried. Also I am using a Virgin Superhub that claims:

```
Software version "R36"
Hardware version 2.00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Your DNS doesn't work the way you expect - it has no association between the hostname `rpi0` and the IP address `192.168.0.4`.

This can have a multitude of reasons, one of them being, that not all home routers keep a local zone at all - if this is the case with your router, you are simply out of luck.

If your router does keep a local zone, make sure your PIs run their DHCP requests with their correct hostnames in place - you can do this by simply disconnecting/reconnecting them after setting the hostname.